# What alternatives to a two-state solution have members of the Israeli Right proposed?

Tags: israel, palestine

Liberal political blogger Josh Marshall just wrote a [blog post](http://talkingpointsmemo.com/edblog/the-un-resolution) discussing the recent U.N. resolution condemning Israeli settlements, but he starts off by discussing the viability of long-term solutions to the Israel-Palestine problem:

> There is no longterm solution to the conflict other than some form of partition of the land. This is dictated by an iron grip of demography and ideology. You can either have partition, a binational state or a state in which Jews and a portion of the Arab population (those who are currently citizens of Israel) have political rights and the majority of Arabs (those who now live in the territories) do not. You can call that last option anything you want. But the countries of the world will never and should never accept it. The binational option would be the end of Zionism and either a politically unstable and unworkable state or a slow motion and perhaps fast motion bloodbath. The least bad option for everyone is partition (indeed, it needn't be a bad option at all with creativity and good will, but both are close to non-existent).
>
> This is obvious. **The alternative ideas one hears from the Zionist right are either ugly or fantastical.**  From a Israeli and Zionist perspective, whether the Palestinians are nice or pragmatic or want peace or don't is basically beside the point. The trajectory is the same regardless. These questions affect timing and process, not end result.

My question is, what are these "alternative ideas" that Marshall is alluding to? Among members of the Israeli Right who do not support a two-state solution, what alternatives have they proposed?

I think there are some on the Israeli Left who support a one-state solution dissolving Israel's identity as a Jewish state and making all Palestinians into Israeli citizens.  But that doesn't strike me as something that anyone on the Israeli Right would support.

Comment: The short answer is Jordan, the nation state conceived for Palestinians

Comment: @KDog You mean sending all the inhabitants of Gaza and the West Bank to Jordan?

Comment: Related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/what-is-israels-long-term-plan-in-the-west-bank

Comment: @KDog and what should happen to the Jordanian people, then? Any link for that proposal?

Comment: @SJuan76 The majority of Jordanians are Palestinians. The vast majority. Can't link on a kindle on vacation

Comment: @KDog Is there enough room in Jordan for all the inhabitants of Gaza and the West Bank as well as the current inhabitants of Jordan?  Has the government of Jordan expressed any willingness to take all the inhabitants of Gaza and the West Bank?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes there is plenty of room. Note that most of the Palestinian refugee camps are in Arab lands. They just won't resettle them.

Comment: @KDog OK, but those refugee camps are not intended to be there forever, the goal is to get those people back into Palestine if and when a Palestinian right of return is secured.  I don't think the government of Jordan is willing to accept all the inhabitants of Gaza and the West Bank as permanent citizens.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan. Go to Powerlineblog and read the Charles Hill article. I'm on a Kindle and can't paste links

Comment: This seems like a logical falsehood as a basis of the question, the assumption is that the right doesn't accept 2 state solution (as opposed to the truth, that it supports 2 state solution, but not the exact form of it that antisemitic left in Europe wants - they don't want Jews ethnically cleansed from where they lived for 1000s of years. You can call Hebron a "settlement" all you want, but Jews lived there 2000 years longer than Arabs). Note that any "two state solutions" proposed by others always ethnically cleanses Jews from one state but not Arabs from another.

Comment: I think there are some on the Israeli Right who oppose a two-state solution.  My question is about those people.

Comment: @user4012 lets have the facts talk: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2014/12/22/map-the-spread-of-israeli-settlements-in-the-west-bank/?utm_term=.e951a02dcc5b. How come settlements are spreading (25% in 5 years) if there is a real intention of leaving them later? This should not be a place for name-calling, warmongering ("everyone who does not agree me is an antisemite", etc., etc.) and other rather silly but mean tactics that only debase the people using them...

Comment: More food for thought (also known as cold facts), the Israeli government has pushed and got approved a new law that is criticized by even the (in @user4012 eyes') "antisemites leftists" of the Israeli Constitutional Court, that would allow to legalize and gives property titles to those settlements that are illegal even under Israeli law. Here is the link form an "antisemite" Israeli newspaper: https://www.justsecurity.org/35743/israels-settlement-regulation-bill-violates-international-law/. Not much of an state left for the other side, isn't it? At least KDog is honest about his intentions...

Comment: @SJuan76 - I'm not willing to engage in play of words with you. You either support ethnic cleansing or not. Making excuses for why you support it is irrelevant (unless you advocate for Arab populations to be called "settlements" too and expelled from Israel? I doubt you are). **The fact that Jews lived in many of those "settlements" (including Jerusalem) well before either 1967 war or 1948 war** makes the whole discussion irrelevant to green borders or anything else.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - your questions says "Israeli right". If you're only interested in specific portions of it that are against 2-state solution, then fix the question (and don't use left wing blogger's opinion as fact).

Comment: @user4012 I edited my title so that it says "What alternatives to a two-state solution have members of the Israeli Right proposed?"  That clearly doesn't mean that everyone on the Israeli Right opposes a two-state solution.  In any case, the entire purpose of my question is to find out what ideas Josh Marshall is referring to when he says "The alternative ideas one hears from the Zionist right are either ugly or fantastical."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - is the "Zionist right" part important to your question?  There are alternatives proposed from other quarters (not even necessarily from Israel). Do you want to include those?

Comment: @user4012 I'm specifically interested in what people on the right have proposed.

Answer (score 20):

First of all, the main option the question is ignoring is that most opponents of the "standard" Arab-imposed 2-state solution idea (return to 1967 lines) are actually in favor of 2-state solution, just in forms different than what Arab states want.

- Dual-citizenship idea. Quoting from Wikipedia:

  > A number of proposals for the granting of Palestinian citizenship or residential permits to Jewish settlers in return for the removal of Israeli military installations from the West Bank have been fielded by such individuals[47] as Arafat,[48] Ibrahim Sarsur[49] and Ahmed Qurei.
  >
  > Israeli Minister Moshe Ya'alon said in April 2010 that "just as Arabs live in Israel, so, too, should Jews be able to live in Palestine." … "If we are talking about coexistence and peace, **why the [Palestinian] insistence that the territory they receive be ethnically cleansed of Jews?**".[50]
- [Populated-Area Exchange Plan (Lieberman plan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieberman_Plan)

  > a territorial exchange whereby Israel would annex almost all Israeli settlements in the West Bank which are situated in major settlement blocs close to the border, and withdraw from the remaining few deep inside the Palestinian territories. At the same time, it would transfer Arab-Israeli areas to the Palestinian state.

Now, as to complete alternatives to two-state solution:

---

[Woodrow Wilson School Graduate Policy Workshop to the Two-State Solution In the Palestinian-Israeli Conflict](https://wws.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/content/other/591d-Workshop-FinalReport-Israel-Main.pdf) compiled a pretty comprehensive list of solutions.

Page 17 of the report lists a summary of main ones (I'm just listing the options themselves and not the workshop's analysis of them):

- Status Quo: Many Israelis, and some Americans, believe that managing the status quo (meaning the continued absence of a formal settlement) is the most viable and feasible alternative to the two-state solution.
- One-state solutions 1: Many left-wing Palestinian academics and activists, and some far-left-wing Israelis, view a one-state solution with equal rights for all inhabitants as the only just solution to the conflict.
- One-state solutions 2: Growing numbers of right-wing Israelis, and Palestinian  cholar Sari Nusseibeh, have promoted a one-state model in which Palestinians
  have limited or different political rights. Numerous variations of both ideas exist based on unitary, federal, binational and confederal models.
- Three-state solution (Israel, West Bank and Gaza): There is a growing belief among some that prolonged West Bank-Gaza divide could become permanent, producing a de facto three-state solution.
- Jordan Option 1: “Jordan is Palestine” idea promoted by far-right Israelis;
- Jordan Option 2: Jordan-Palestine confederation promoted by some Jordanians.
- Egypt-Gaza Option: Some far-right Israelis would like Egypt to annex or assume greater responsibility for Gaza.
- Trusteeship: Interim international administration over the future Palestinian state

Comment: All the bullet points in the second part of the answer are full quotes from WW report, I just decided to omit the blockquote markup as they are all quotes.

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it directly answered the question of "which right-wing solutions is Marshall probably referring to as 'ugly and fantastical'?"  As is, I'm guessing One-state solutions 2 and possibly Jordan Option 1 or Egypt-Gaza Option.  It's not clear to me what makes the latter two options "ugly".

Comment: @Brythan - Marshall is arguing against straman, so I don't want to dignify his ideological ramblings with attempts to figure out what he was referring to since he didn't bother saying so himself. Frankly, I'm more than tempted to edit out any mention of that personage out of the question and turn it into a neutral "what are proposed alternatives to 2 state solution", but not sure if OP would strongly object.

Answer (score 7):

First, I want to point out that the occuapation is 50 years old. It
has worked fairly well for Israel and its goals regarding regional
security and territorial expansion have largely been achieved.

It might seem strange to say that a day after four Israeli soldiers
were killed by an Arab Israeli ramming them with a truck. But look at
the numbers, terrorism has waned over the years and the number of
*successful* attacks are record low.

At the same time, Israel has improved its image in the Arab world. One
example is the Arab Peace Initiative, presented by the Saudi king in
2002, which offered Israel peace and recognition in exchange for
withdrawal from the territories captured in 1967. Such an initiative
would have been unthinkable in the 1980's.

For Israel, things are moving in the right direction albeit
slowly. The state knows there is a cost to the occupation, but so far
it has been willing to shoulder it. Therefore it seems most likely
that the state will uphold the status quo but advance its interest in
key areas such as strengthening its grip on East Jerusalem.

@user4012's answer is a good summary of the most popular solutions to
the Palestine question. So I will just describe the right-wing
ones. Remember that these aren't (currently) seriously considered by
the Israeli establishment.

### Annexation of Area C

Education minister, Naftali Bennett [wants to annex Area C](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2016/06/08/israeli-minister-wants-to-annex-half-of-west-bank-and-kick-out-the-palestinians/?utm_term=.aec45a321a61) of the West Bank. It corresponds to the white area of this map:

[image: Area C of the West Bank]

He is the leader of the right-wing [Jewish
Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jewish_Home) party which
currently holds 8 of 120 seats in the Knesset (Israeli parliament).

I think Marhall thinks this solution is "ugly or fantastical" because
constructing a state out of the yellow areas of the West Bank would be
impossible. The Palestinians in those areas would be living in a
territorial void without political rights.

### Population Transfer

Likely the "ugly or fantastical" idea Marshall has in mind. The idea
is described in *[A History of the Concept of "Transfer" in
Zionism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2537340)* by Israel Shahak:

> Since early summer 1987, a movement has been growing in
>   Israeli-Jewish society which supports the idea of expelling all
>   Palestinians from the West Bank and Gaza Strip to neighboring Arab
>   countries or, preferably, beyond. The present plans resemble older
>   Zionist attempts or plans for the expulsion of Palestinians,
>   referred to euphemistically as 'transfer' plans. It must be
>   emphasized that the existence of a very strong minority that
>   advocates this idea, combined with the support or at very least the
>   lack of opposition from influential personalities, makes this idea
>   of 'transfer' a potentially very dangerous one. Indeed, a
>   significant minority of Israeli Jews takes this option seriously. In
>   general, opposition inside Israel to transfer includes people from
>   across the political spectrum, but it is much stronger among the
>   secular than among the religious.

This idea was advocated by [Meir
Kahane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Kahane) of the right-wing
[Kach party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kach_and_Kahane_Chai) which
was banned in 1994.

A more recent party supporting "transfer" is Benny Elon of the
[Molodet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moledet) party. His ideas,
formulated in the [Elon
Plan](http://www.antiwar.com/hacohen/?articleid=11754) is a mix of
forced and voluntary expulsion of Palestinians from the West Bank. He
notes that about half of all Palestinians would be willing to emigrate
given [the right incentives](http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-3319132,00.html):

> "It can be examined whether it is not more humane, still, to give a
>   million families 100,000 dollars each, and have them rebuild their
>   lives, in the same way that my father, a refugee from Dusseldorf,
>   and the refugees from Morocco and other places did when they built
>   this country…"

An even more recent example is [Baruch
Marzel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Marzel) of the now
defunct [Jewish National
Front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_National_Front).

https://972mag.com/israels-extremist-settlers-are-aiming-for-the-mainstream/119868/

It's important to note that these ideas are only propagated by the
right-wing of the right-wing. Those who consider Benjamin Netanyahu a
leftist.

Answer (score 3):

(I highly doubt Marshall was referring to this solution, but it does answer the question, as it is a proposal from a member of the Israeli right -- Dr. Mordechai Kedar, the noted Israeli scholar of Arabic culture and lecturer in the Arabic Studies department at Bar-Ilan University.)

Any solution must pass the following litmus test: **will it provide political stability to the Palestinian people?**

The Palestinian Authority already fails this test abysmally. It holds power only because of its role as the largest employer in the area, because of the brutal repression it carries out against all dissenters, and because it cooperates with Israeli security forces. While Abbas is reported to be in good health, he's in his 80s and I suggest it's unwise to count on this state of affairs continuing much longer.

At this point, history demonstrates that any solution that involves a state run by Palestinians -- either a two-state solution, or a binational single state -- is liable to either fall into the same mold as the PA -- a secular regime repressing any sort of dissent -- or become like Hamas-run Gaza, a terrorist organization whose goal is to destroy Israel and push sharia law on the world. Neither possibility, nor the even worse case of a pendulum swinging back and forth between the two, can remotely provide political stability to the Palestinian people.

But if we look at the Middle East, there are a few countries who have achieved political stability, and thus economic stability, and even almost fantastic wealth -- the United Arab Emirates, Qatar, Kuwait and Bahrain.

Dr. Kedar's thesis is that these countries (the UAE is actually a loose federation of sovereign states, much like the EU) are each built around a single tribe. Because tribal loyalty is still an extremely powerful force in the Middle East, nation-states built around the traditional tribal structure have far more staying power.

In contrast, Syria, Lebanon, Iraq, Iran, are all aggregates of tribes / ethnic groups / religious groups. The subgroup on top uses brutal force to maintain its hold on all the others, while the other subgroups constantly wage a near-existential battle to reach the top.

Dr. Kedar argues the same is true of the Palestinian people. Fatah is resented by the local families as much for its interloper status as for its failures. Per Dr. Kedar, the measure of tribal loyalty is the degree of intermarriage; the different families generally do not intermarry with each other.

Thus, in order to provide political and economic stability, the international community should push Israel to negotiate directly with the individual families, creating a separate and independent emirate for each one if they so wish. The resultant emirate city-states would be politically stable, because local authorities would have the greatest interest in policing their own people, but would not be resented as some kind of overlordship.

Dr. Kedar has identified 7 polities, in addition to Gaza. Each emirate would act with independent sovereignty, control its own economy, educational system and form of government. They might band together a la the UAE -- United Palestinian Emirates -- or they might keep separate.

This plan also benefits Israel. It addresses Israel's security needs. Stable political systems would be an incredible boon to Israel, but the economic benefits and interactions would outweigh even those.

The stability of the proposed emirates would make them greatly attractive targets for foreign investment. But even the local economy could see rapid gains, particularly if the emirates would leverage agreements with Israel in that direction. For example, Hebron used to have a thriving leather-working industry; but it failed when Israel began importing cheap leather from other sources. As part of the agreements between Hebron and Israel, Hebron could demand an Israeli tax hike on the imported leather, to make Hebron leather profitable once more.

Answer (score 0):

I recall hearing talk of a 3-state solution during the George W Bush administration: Israel as-now, West Bank as a PLO-run state and Gaza as a Hamas-run state.

For now though, I think the political actors are happy with the status quo so expect greater amount of settlements into West Bank, violence in new settlements from Palestinians in reaction to encroachment and then wall extension and construction as Israel's booming economy gobbles up more land whereas the hobbled Palestinian economy continues to underperform.

Answer (score -2):

Even otherwise right now in 2017 many even pro-Palestinians  feel that the two state solution, advocated tirelessly by mediocre politicians who lack historical vision, is therefore unrealistic, unworkable and dangerous. Unrealistic and unworkable because one can’t unscramble an egg, and dangerous because genuine grievances can’t be suppressed permanently by shortsighted political decisions.

Moreover, Jews, Muslims, Christians and others would be perfectly free to practice their religious beliefs and, unlike the current situation, would enjoy unfettered access to their respective holy places. And all would be treated equally before the law as citizens.

Furthermore, every citizen would be free to live wherever he or she likes in accordance with the law. For example, a Jew would be free to settle anywhere in Israel/Palestine. A Palestinian would be accorded the same right.

Nonetheless, the two communities must realize by now that that they have to reform and amend their old, anachronistic ways and especially their views of each other.

Palestinians will have to discard, once and for all, their dreams of cleansing Palestine of Ashkenazi and other Jews who arrived in the country following WWII.

Likewise, Jews must come to terms with the fact that Palestinians have at least an equal right to this land of Israel/Palestine.

This vision of one-state for all, where Jews and Palestinians live equally and peacefully in a unitary, democratic, civil state is not too idealistic to be practical. It happened in South Africa; and it is practiced in many countries all over the globe.

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE, we normally expect answers to be backed up with credible/official sources, could you provide any for this answer?

Comment: Even more problematic, this doesn't answer the question.  The question is what the Israeli right thinks should be done, not what should actually be done.  Perhaps this responds to one of the other answers, but it is not itself an answer to this question.